# how can i to enable @defer directive in apollo server express

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server, graphql-js

How can I enable `@defer` in apollo server express . The documentation doesn't show how to use this handler

```
const graphqlHandler = async (
  req: express.Request,
  res: express.Response,
  next
) => {
  const a = runHttpQuery([req, res], {
    method: req.method,
    options: options,
    query: req.method === "POST" ? req.body : req.query,
    request: convertNodeHttpToRequest(req),
    enableDefer: true,
  }).then(() => {});
};
```

Comment: Show us a link to the docs mentioning the defer annotation and we might help you

Comment: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/defer-support/docs/source/defer-support.md

Comment: Thank you for that. That it a lot clearer! I thought you were trying to use some kind of annotation on the typescript code, but it was just how to process GraphQL queries that used the `@defer` directive.

That branch you link to has not been updated in 3 years. It was never merged into `main`. My guess is that it does not exist in the API at all and only as a branch experiment.

Comment: I had no idea, thanks alot